# str.match is not matching exactly due to no taking into account characters that follow

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file:

```
State,  Region                  
AK,     Pacific Non Continuous
HI,     Pacific Non Continuous 
AL,     East South Central  
AZ,     Mountain                
CA,     Pacific                
OR,     Pacific
```

When I run:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:...\input.csv')

df['SuperRegion'] = pd.np.where(df.Region.str.match("New England|Middle Atlantic|South Atlantic"), "East",
                pd.np.where(df.Region.str.match("East North Central|East South Central|West North Central|West South Central"), "Mid West",
                pd.np.where(df.Region.str.match("Mountain|Pacific"), "West", "Other")))

df.to_csv('C:...\Output.csv', index=False)
```

I expect the `SuperRegion` value to be `Other` for the first two rows

```
State,  Region,                  SuperRegion
AK,     Pacific Non Continuous,  **Other**
HI,     Pacific Non Continuous,  **Other**
AL,     East South Central,      Mid West
AZ,     Mountain,                West
CA,     Pacific,                 West
OR,     Pacific,                 West
```

But instead I get:

```
State,  Region,                  SuperRegion
AK,     Pacific Non Continuous,  **West**
HI,     Pacific Non Continuous,  **West**
AL,     East South Central,      Mid West
AZ,     Mountain,                West
CA,     Pacific,                 West
OR,     Pacific,                 West
```

I am assuming when it is runs it does not differentiate between `Pacific` and `Pacific Non Continuous` as I would like it to. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not change:

```
pd.np.where(df.Region.str.match("Mountain|Pacific"), "West", "Other")))
```

to:

```
pd.np.where(df.Region.str.match("Mountain|Pacific|Pacific Non Continuous"), "West", "West", "Other")))
```

Or add the case separately:

```
df['SuperRegion'] = pd.np.where(df.Region.str.match("New England|Middle Atlantic|South Atlantic"), "East",
                pd.np.where(df.Region.str.match("East North Central|East South Central|West North Central|West South Central"), "Mid West",
                pd.np.where(df.Region.str.match("Pacific Non Continuous"), "Other",
                pd.np.where(df.Region.str.match("Mountain|Pacific"), "West")))
```

The ideal solution for this would be to create a dictionary with key as regions and values as superregions and use

```
df['Regions'].map(dict)
```

Comment: I added the match to <Pacific Non Continuous> before the match to <Pacific>, as you noted above, and it worked great! Thanks. I am surprised there isn't an exact match command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isin()

```
df['SuperRegion'] = np.where(df.Region.isin(['New England','Middle Atlantic','South Atlantic']), "East",\
np.where(df.Region.isin(["East North Central","East South Central","West North Central","West South Central"]), "Mid West",\
np.where(df.Region.isin(["Mountain","Pacific"]), "West", "Other")))
```

You get

```
    State   Region                  SuperRegion
0   AK      Pacific Non Continuous  Other
1   HI      Pacific Non Continuous  Other
2   AL      East South Central      Mid West
3   AZ      Mountain                West
4   CA      Pacific                 West
5   OR      Pacific                 West
```